# Sinkhorn Knopp algorithm convergence proof

Tags: matrices, algorithms

Do you know where I can find an 'elegant' proof of convergence of the Sinkhorn Knopp algorithm?

The original paper by Sinkhorn and Knopp contains a costructive proof which is elementary but too intricate.

Other papers I found deal with the rate of convergence of the algorithm but they assume that the algorithm converges (obviously for a certain class of matrices).

Comment: A proof that the algorithm converges at a specified rate is a proof that the algorithm converges.

Comment: Not if to prove it you assume that the algorithm converges.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a paper with a proof of convergence (see Section 2), based on some simple facts about so-called Kullback-Leibler divergence. Is this elegant enough?

[D. Chakrabarty and S. Channa: Better and Simpler Error Analysis of the Sinkhorn-Knopp Algorithm for Matrix Scaling](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.02790.pdf)

Comment: Not so elegant as I was finding, it is also to intricate for me. But thank you anyway.